# Java, código de interfaz de imágenes

Tags: java, java-swing

```
private Object[][] datosProductos = {
            {"Martillo", "Martillo de carpintero", 10, "$15.50"},
            {"Destornillador", "Destornillador plano", 20, "$7.25"},
            {"Sierra", "Sierra para madera", 5, "$32.75"},
            {"Cinta métrica", "Cinta métrica de 3 metros", 15, "$5.99"},
            {"Llave ajustable", "Llave ajustable de 10 pulgadas", 8, "$12.50"},
            {"Alicate", "Alicate de punta larga", 12, "$9.75"},
            {"Taladro", "Taladro eléctrico de 3/8 pulgadas", 3, "$49.99"},
            {"Clavos", "Caja de clavos de 2 pulgadas", 25, "$2.50"},
            {"Pegamento", "Tubo de pegamento para madera", 18, "$3.75"},
            {"Pintura", "Lata de pintura blanca de 1 galón", 6, "$22.99"},
            {"Lijadora", "Lijadora orbital de 5 pulgadas", 4, "$39.99"},
            {"Brocas", "Juego de brocas para taladro ", 9, "$14.50"},
            {"Cepillo de alambre", "Cepillo de alambre para metal", 7, "$6.25"},
            {"Nivel", "Nivel de burbuja de 24 pulgadas", 2, "$17.99"},
            {"Serrucho", "Serrucho de mano para madera", 11, "$8.99"}
};
```

A este código, quiero agregarle imágenes de cada producto, cómo puedo hacerlo?, ya que estoy usando interfaz gráfica, pero por código.

Comment: No se me ocurre como podrías añadirle un imagen a un objeto, creo que no se puede... pero puedes usar el componente de JLabel para incluir imágenes. Como tienes todo el código?

Comment: Depende si usas el mapa de bits o la ruta a la imagen o un recurso ¿Cuál es el origen de la imagen?; en cualquier caso es mucho mejor que declares la clase Producto.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es tan simple como, "agregala".

```
ImageIcon mar = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "/mar.png" )  );
ImageIcon des = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "/des.png" )  );

private Object[][] datosProductos = {
    { "Martillo", "Martillo de carpintero", 10, "$15.50", mar },
    { "Destornillador", "Destornillador plano", 20, "$7.25", des }            
};
```

Todas las clases heredan de `Object`, por lo que dentro de **`datosProductos`** puedes meter "cualquier cosa".
La única consideración, es a la hora de usar los objetos guardados.
Por ejemplo, si quieres obtener el precio:

```
double precioProducto;
precioProducto = Double.valueOf(((String) datosProductos[ 0 ][ 3 ] ).substring( 1 ));
```

y la imagen:

```
ImageIcon imagenProducto = (ImageIcon) datosProductos[ 0 ][ 4 ];
```